# Ansible: Invalid syntax in Conditional

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a playbook to verifie a space on the datastore before create a VM and I need the creation to `fail if datastore usage > 80 %`.

My playbook is like the below and I am stuck on the conditional check invalids syntax.

```yaml
- name: Get VM datastore info
  vmware_datastore_facts:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_server }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
    datacenter: "{{data_center}}"
    validate_certs: False
    name: "{{ vm_datastore }}"
  register: datastore
  delegate_to: localhost

- set_fact:
    datastore_capacity: "{{ datastore.datastores[0].capacity }}"
    datastore_freeSpace: "{{ datastore.datastores[0].freeSpace}}"
   
- fail:
    msg: "No more space on VMware datastore"
  when:
    -  ' ("{{datastore_freeSpace}}" // "{{datastore_capacity}}")  * 100) > 80'
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Fail if datastore usage > 80%"***

A: Try this:

```yaml
      when: 100 - (datastore_freeSpace|int / datastore_capacity|int * 100) > 80
```

, or this (the same but decimal, instead of the percentage)

```yaml
      when: 1.0 - datastore_freeSpace|int / datastore_capacity|int > 0.8
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    datastore:
      datastores:
        - capacity: 100
          freeSpace: 10
  
    datastore_capacity: "{{ datastore.datastores[0].capacity }}"
    datastore_freeSpace: "{{ datastore.datastores[0].freeSpace}}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          datastore_capacity: {{ datastore_capacity }}
          datastore_freeSpace: {{ datastore_freeSpace }}
          datastore_capacity|type_debug: {{ datastore_capacity|type_debug }}
          datastore_freeSpace|type_debug: {{ datastore_freeSpace|type_debug }}
          used[%]: {{ 100 - (datastore_freeSpace|int / datastore_capacity|int * 100) }}

          
    - debug:
        msg: "No more space on VMware datastore"
      when: 100 - (datastore_freeSpace|int / datastore_capacity|int * 100) > 80
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    datastore_capacity: 100
    datastore_freeSpace: 10
    datastore_capacity|type_debug: str
    datastore_freeSpace|type_debug: str
    used[%]: 90.0

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: No more space on VMware datastore

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```